# I can't set custom font in android view

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner to choose between some custom fonts. so I tried following codes to set this spinner. But there is an error says (cannot resolve symbol creatFromAsset).
I don't know where I made a mistake!

```
try {
      font.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fonts)); 
} catch (Exception ex){
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"setAdapters Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

font.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                Typeface typeface  = new  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"assets/Xanadu.ttf");
                edt2.setTypeface(typeface);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what is the context of this code? in an object definition or inside an onCreate?

Comment: try `this.getAssets()`

Answer (score 2):

`TypeFace` constructor is not public, so you can't use `new`.

Do instead:

`Typeface typeface  = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Xanadu.ttf");`

Answer (score 1):

`getAssets` itself points to the folder of assets and you have no need to repeat **assets** again in file address:

```
Typeface typeface  = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Xanadu.ttf");
```

Comment: i made this changes but it still says (cannot resolve symbol 'creatFromAsset') :(